# How do I run Webpack DevServer and Flask with Docker?

Tags: docker, flask, webpack

I can't seem to figure out how to run Flask Backend with Webpack Dev Server. The flask routes have a login decorator. Webpack serves my assets but I can't access any backend routes. Client side I prefix the routes with port `:8080/someFlaskRoute` but that get's redirected to `/login` which isn't on port 8080?

route decorator:

```
def login_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        expiration = session.get('expires', 0)
        now = int(time.time())
        if expiration == 0 or expiration < now or 'user_id' not in session:
            return redirect(url_for('saml_login', _external=True, _scheme='https', next=request.url))
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    return decorated_function
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
    server-dev:
        build:
            context: ../..
            dockerfile: Dockerfile-server-base
        network_mode: host
        ports:
            - 10005:10005
        tty: true
        stdin_open: true
        command: uwsgi --http-socket 0.0.0.0:10005 --http-websockets --module myapp:app --master --processes 4 --enable-threads --honour-stdin --py-autoreload=3 --buffer-size=65535

    client-dev:
        image: node:12.13.1-slim
        network_mode: host
        ports:
            - 10001:10001
            - 3000:3000
        command: yarn dev
```

Webpack Dev Server:

```
devServer: {
  host: '0.0.0.0',
  public: '0.0.0.0:0',
  port: 10001,
  sockPort: 80,
  hotOnly: true,
  publicPath: '/',
  headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' }
}
```

I see the request come in in the logs:

`server-dev_1  | [pid: 119|app: 0|req: 1/1] 127.0.0.1 () {52 vars in 1051 bytes} [Wed Jun 10 10:00:03 2020] GET /dashboard/all_data?is_alignment=false&group_id=&hkrgy8asx787tzwnvf2wll => generated 561 bytes in 5 msecs (HTTP/1.1 302) 3 headers in 272 bytes (1 switches on core 0)`

But the response header gives me this:

```
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 561
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 10 Jun 2020 10:00:03 GMT
Location: /login/?next=http%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com%2Fdashboard%2Fall_data
Generated-By: dev-machine
Server: nginx
```

nginx config:

```
upstream flask_upstream {
  server localhost:10005;
}
server {
  listen 8080;
  server_name ~^(?!api).*.mysite.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://flask_upstream;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol ssl;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf;
    set $upstream_name flask_upstream;
  }
}
```

Comment: Where does port 8080 come from; none of the code you show references it at all?  Is the session cookie getting through?  Can you use something like webpack-dev-server's [`proxy`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy) configuration so this all runs on the same host/port from the browser's point of view?

Comment: 8080 seems how we've set up our nginx, it translates requets on 8080 to 10005. I tried using the webpack proxy config but couldnt get it working. It seems like when the :8080 request is sent to Flask, it's redirecting to `/login` doesn't keep the port.